# SWIG shows error when wrapping C++ for Java

Tags: java, c++, cmd, swig

I want to wrap a c++ class using SWIG for java. I've followed the [official tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) and [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#running_swig) and tried to make it work, but I get some errors.
I use windows 7 x64.

So I opened cmd and typed:`swig -c++  -java myclass.i`

That command executed and generated few files.(it did not produce errors)

After that, I typed in: `gcc -c myclass_wrap.cxx  -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\include\win32"`

And that command was successful as well. (did not produce errors)

Finally, I typed in `ld -G myclass_wrap.o  -o libmyclass.so`

which produced bunch of undefined reference errors like:

`myclass_wrap.o:myclass_wrap.cxx:<.text+0xa8>: undefined reference to '__cxa_allocate_exception'`

Here is my initial c++ code, the following c++ class:
header file:

```
/*myclass.h*/
#define MYCLASS_H
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
private:
    int ID;
    std::vector<int> vector;

public:
    myClass();
    myClass(int id, std::vector<int> v);

    void setID(int id);
    int getID();

    void setVector(std::vector<int> v);
    std::vector<int> getVector();

    void insertIntoVector(int num);
    void printVector();
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

and cpp file:

```
/*myclass.cpp*/
#include "myclass.h"
myClass::myClass()
{
    ID=0;
    vector=std::vector<int>();
}

myClass::myClass(int id, std::vector<int> v)
{
    ID=id;
    vector=v;
}

void myClass::setID(int id)
{
    ID=id;
}

int myClass::getID()
{
    return ID;
}


void myClass::setVector(std::vector<int> v)
{
    vector=v;
}
std::vector<int> myClass::getVector()
{
    return vector;
}

void myClass::insertIntoVector(int num)
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    it=vector.end();
    vector.insert(it,num);
}

void myClass::printVector()
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it=vector.begin(); it<vector.end(); it++)
        std::cout << ' ' << *it<< std::endl;
}
```

and the swig module file:

```
/*myclass.i*/    
%module test
%{
#include "myclass.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
   %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
}

%include "myclass.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After that, I typed in: `gcc -c myclass_wrap.cxx -I"C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\include" -I"C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\include\win32"`

It's C++ code, so in general prefer to compile with `g++` instead of `gcc` (though not strictly necessary):

`g++ -c myclass_wrap.cxx -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\include\win32"`

> Finally, I typed in `ld -G myclass_wrap.o -o libmyclass.so`
>
> which produced bunch of undefined reference errors like:
>
> myclass_wrap.o:myclass_wrap.cxx:<.text+0xa8>: undefined reference to
>   '__cxa_allocate_exception'

That example for building a shared library from the SWIG documentation was not for C++ (so C++-specific symbols were not found by the linker), nor was it for Windows.

Assuming you're using the Mingw version of gcc for Windows, use the following to compile a DLL `myclass.dll` instead:

`g++ -shared -o myclass.dll myclass_wrap.o`

For more information on building a DLL with Mingw, [see this example on the Mingw site](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll).

See also [this SWIG FAQ page](http://www.dabeaz.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?SwigFaq/SharedLibraries) which has links to information about building shared libraries or DLLs for a variety of platforms and compilers (but beware many example commands are for C rather than C++).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it out as soon as I get back home (in few hours), and I'll post the results. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hello @softwariness , I did everything what you said, but the command which should produce shared library `g++ -shared -o myclass.dll myclass_wrap.o` produces undefined reference errors for all functions in myclass.cpp . And in the end, final error was `Id returned 1 exit status`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I DID IT! :) . I googled a bit, and I found that I am supposed to compile not just the example_wrap.cxx but example.cpp also with the g++ compiler. I did it and I had to modify the last command to this: `g++ -shared -o myclass.dll myclass_wrap.o myclass.o` , and the dll file was created :) .